# Write a MySQL query to calculate the weekly retention of users based on their sign-up cohort

Tags: mysql

I need to write a MySQL query to calculate weekly retention of users from the two tables (not sure if both are needed).

[events table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mP766.png)

| user_id | event_type | event_name | location | device | user_type | occurred_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10522 | engagement | login | Japan | dell inspiron notebook | 3 | 2014-05-02 11:02:00 |
| 10522 | engagement | home_page | Japan | dell inspiron notebook | 3 | 2014-05-02 11:02:00 |
| 10522 | engagement | like_message | Japan | dell inspiron notebook | 3 | 2014-05-02 11:03:00 |
| 10522 | engagement | view_inbox | Japan | dell inspiron notebook | 3 | 2014-05-02 11:04:00 |
| 10522 | engagement | search_run | Japan | dell inspiron notebook | 3 | 2014-05-02 11:03:00 |
| 10612 | engagement | send_message | Netherlands | iphone 5 | 1 | 2014-05-01 10:00:00 |
| 11037 | engagement | search_autocomplete | United Kingdom | iphone 4s | 1 | 2014-05-01 07:25:00 |
| 11536 | engagement | search_click_result_10 | Taiwan | macbook air | 2 | 2014-05-05 11:04:00 |
| 11768 | signup_flow | complete_signup | France | macbook pro | 3 | 2014-05-01 08:03:00 |

[users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3sa9.png)

| user_id | company_id | language | state | created_at | activated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2242 | 1 | german | active | 2013-06-20 18:32:00 | 2013-06-20 18:34:00 |
| 2243 | 17 | french | active | 2013-06-20 16:32:00 | 2013-06-20 16:33:00 |
| 2240 | 11565 | english | active | 2013-06-20 15:41:00 | 2013-06-20 15:43:00 |
| 2235 | 378 | spanish | active | 2013-06-19 19:56:00 | 2013-06-19 19:58:00 |
| 2234 | 1160 | english | active | 2013-06-19 13:39:00 | 2013-06-19 13:40:00 |
| 2225 | 2480 | english | active | 2013-06-19 11:19:00 | 2013-06-19 11:21:00 |
| 2217 | 3474 | english | active | 2013-06-19 09:16:00 | 2013-06-19 09:17:00 |
| 2222 | 9658 | spanish | active | 2013-06-19 08:52:00 | 2013-06-19 08:54:00 |
| 2223 | 23 | english | active | 2013-06-19 02:56:00 | 2013-06-19 02:58:00 |

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT
  DATE(u.activated_at) AS cohort_start_date,
  WEEK(e.occurred_at) AS week_number,
  COUNT(DISTINCT e.user_id) AS active_users,
  COUNT(DISTINCT u.user_id) AS total_users,
  COUNT(DISTINCT e.user_id) / COUNT(DISTINCT u.user_id) * 100 AS retention_rate
FROM
  users u
JOIN events e ON u.user_id = e.user_id
WHERE
  e.event_type = 'engagement'
GROUP BY
  cohort_start_date, week_number
ORDER BY
  cohort_start_date, week_number;
```

Comment: For those of us that have no idea what retention means you could explain in words and publish sample data and desired outcome as text. And what does doesn't work mean- is there an error or do you not get the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate the count of users activated on a given date, and the aggregation of their activity in a given week. You also need to use [`YEARWEEK(date,mode)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) instead of `WEEK`. I think this will produce the stats you are looking for:

```
WITH cohorts AS (
    SELECT
        DATE(activated_at) AS cohort_start_date,
        COUNT(*) AS total_users
    FROM users
    GROUP BY 1
),
weekly_stats AS (
    SELECT
        DATE(u.activated_at) AS cohort_start_date,
        YEARWEEK(e.occurred_at, 0) AS year_week,
        COUNT(DISTINCT e.user_id) AS active_users
    FROM users u
    JOIN events e ON u.user_id = e.user_id
    WHERE e.event_type = 'engagement'
    GROUP BY cohort_start_date, year_week
)
SELECT
    cohorts.cohort_start_date,
    weekly_stats.year_week,
    weekly_stats.active_users,
    cohorts.total_users AS total_users,
    weekly_stats.active_users / cohorts.total_users * 100 AS retention_rate
FROM cohorts
JOIN weekly_stats
    ON cohorts.cohort_start_date = weekly_stats.cohort_start_date
ORDER BY cohort_start_date, year_week;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9JbNLAsq).